# Filling a ListView with data from cursor

Tags: android, listview, android-cursor

I'm trying to fill a ListView with a Telephone number and a date from a cursor, but I don't know what I am doing wrong:

```
String[] cols = new String[]{ConcursoProvider.PARTICIPANTE_TELEFONO,ConcursoProvider.PARTICIPANTE_FECHA};

    ConcursoProvider.tabla_Elegida = ConcursoProvider.TABLA_PARTICIPANTE;
    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(ConcursoProvider.CONTENT_URI,cols,null , null, null);

    ListView lista = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listaAcertantes);
    int[] ids ={android.R.id.text1,android.R.id.text2};
    lista.setAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,c,cols,ids,0));
```

The logcat show me this:

```
08-22 07:47:02.951: E/AndroidRuntime(13442): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-22 07:47:02.951: E/AndroidRuntime(13442): Process: com.example.proyectosms, PID: 13442
08-22 07:47:02.951: E/AndroidRuntime(13442): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.proyectosms/com.example.proyectosms.AcertantesActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
08-22 07:47:02.951: E/AndroidRuntime(13442):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
08-22 07:47:02.951: E/AndroidRuntime(13442):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
08-22 07:47:02.951: E/AndroidRuntime(13442):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
08-22 07:47:02.951: E/AndroidRuntime(13442):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
08-22 07:47:02.951: E/AndroidRuntime(13442):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-22 07:47:02.951: E/AndroidRuntime(13442):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-22 07:47:02.951: E/AndroidRuntime(13442):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-22 07:47:02.951: E/AndroidRuntime(13442):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-22 07:47:02.951: E/AndroidRuntime(13442):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-22 07:47:02.951: E/AndroidRuntime(13442):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-22 07:47:02.951: E/AndroidRuntime(13442):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-22 07:47:02.951: E/AndroidRuntime(13442):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-22 07:47:02.951: E/AndroidRuntime(13442): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
08-22 07:47:02.951: E/AndroidRuntime(13442):    at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:303)
08-22 07:47:02.951: E/AndroidRuntime(13442):    at android.database.CursorWrapper.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CursorWrapper.java:78)
08-22 07:47:02.951: E/AndroidRuntime(13442):    at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.init(CursorAdapter.java:174)
08-22 07:47:02.951: E/AndroidRuntime(13442):    at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.<init>(CursorAdapter.java:151)
08-22 07:47:02.951: E/AndroidRuntime(13442):    at android.support.v4.widget.ResourceCursorAdapter.<init>(ResourceCursorAdapter.java:93)
08-22 07:47:02.951: E/AndroidRuntime(13442):    at android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.<init>(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:89)
08-22 07:47:02.951: E/AndroidRuntime(13442):    at com.example.proyectosms.AcertantesActivity.RellenarLista(AcertantesActivity.java:41)
08-22 07:47:02.951: E/AndroidRuntime(13442):    at com.example.proyectosms.AcertantesActivity.onCreate(AcertantesActivity.java:30)
08-22 07:47:02.951: E/AndroidRuntime(13442):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
08-22 07:47:02.951: E/AndroidRuntime(13442):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-22 07:47:02.951: E/AndroidRuntime(13442):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
08-22 07:47:02.951: E/AndroidRuntime(13442):    ... 11 more
```

I think it is asking me for the column "_id" , but I don't want to show that value.

Comment: please show us Your database class (I think it´s ConcursoProvider, right?)...

Comment: Exception it's saying that you don't have column named "_id"

Comment: `CursorAdapters` need a `_id` column. Otherwise they don't work. It doesn't mean you have to display this `_id` value, the `CursorAdapter` just needs it internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs,

> To back a ListView with a Cursor, the cursor must contain a column named _ID. Because of this, the query shown previously retrieves the _ID column for the "words" table, even though the ListView doesn't display it. This restriction also explains why most providers have a _ID column for each of their tables.

Please read up on [Content Provider Basics](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html#DisplayResults)

Answer (score 0):

Your table is missing **_id** column.

In your  `CREATE TABLE`  query add `_id` column.

For example:

```
 String CREATE_TABLE= " CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"+COLUMN1+" TEXT,"+COLUMN2+" TEXT,"+COLUMN3+" INTEGER)";
```

Or

implement `BaseColumns` where you define all columns of your table.

For example:

```
   public static class Entry implements BaseColumns {
          public final String idd;
        public final String title;
        public final String link;
        public final String summary;
        public final Long published;

        private Entry(String id,String title, String summary, String link, long published) {
            this.title = title;
            this.summary = summary;
            this.link = link;
            this.idd=id;
            this.published=published;
        }
    }
```

When you implement `BaseColumns` it will automatically add `_id` column to your table.

While doing this don't forget to change your database version.

Comment: it has the column _id ;)